# PowerShell Oracle Procedure Looping Files

Tags: oracle, file, powershell, loops, foreach

I've got several banking txt files that I need to upload the content to a Oracle Server. I'll use the `UTL_FILE` package on oracle within a store procedure. But I need a loop that would read the name of the files, and the name of two directories above, one directory is a payment type and the above is the name of the Bank.

```
Ex.:

 c:\bb\cobranca\file.txt

 v_bank := itau_bank

 v_type := boleto

 v_file := return_file.txt
```

With those variables I would call my store procedure using `sqlplus`.

I am trying something like this on `PowerShell`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Exclude *.ps1| 
Foreach-Object {


    $v_file = Split-Path ($_.FullName) -Leaf #file.txt this variable is ok

    $v_type = Split-Path ($_.FullName) -Parent #c:\temp\retorno\bb\cobranca this variable should be only "cobranca"

    $v_bank = Split-Path ($_.FullName) -Parent #c:\temp\retorno\bb\cobranca this variable should be only "bb"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data.OracleClient") 

$connectionString = "Data Source=***;uid=***;pwd=***";          
$inputString0 = $v_file;
$inputString1 = $v_type;
$inputString2 = $v_bank;

$oracleConnection = new-object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection($connectionString);
$cmd = new-object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand;
$cmd.Connection = $oracleConnection;

$cmd.CommandText = "PROC_UPLOAD_CONTENT";
$cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure;

$cmd.Parameters.Add("inputString0", [System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType]::VarChar2) | out-null;
$cmd.Parameters["inputString0"].Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Input;
$cmd.Parameters["inputString0"].Value = $inputString0;

$cmd.Parameters.Add("inputString1", [System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType]::VarChar2) | out-null;
$cmd.Parameters["inputString1"].Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Input;
$cmd.Parameters["inputString1"].Value = $inputString1;

$cmd.Parameters.Add("inputString2", [System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType]::VarChar2) | out-null;
$cmd.Parameters["inputString2"].Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Input;
$cmd.Parameters["inputString2"].Value = $inputString2;

$oracleConnection.Open();
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
$oracleConnection.Close();


}
```

I'm not getting the variables the way i need to pass then to the oracle store procedure.

Comment: Is the content of each file structured in the same way?

Comment: i will load to a table that has single column named line each line of the files.

Comment: So is your question how to extract `'cobranca'` and `'bb'` directory names from the full file path?

Comment: That is it APC.